# Code Synthesis XSD parsing/data binding xml string instead of xml file

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, xml-parsing, codesynthesis

I have seen tutorials all over the place for explaining how to get Code Synthesis xsd to work if you provide the xml in a file on your system, but I have not been able to find anything about providing the xml as a string.

I am receiving the xml from a TCP connection and I am attempting to parse it with Code Synthesis xsd, and it just seems like a useless additional step to create an xml file when I already have it in memory as a string.

And yes, this is in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use std::istringstream to make a string appear as std::istream and then parse that:

```
#include <sstream>

std::string str = ... // Input XML in a string.
std::istringstream istr (str);

std::auto_ptr<root_type> r = root (istr);
```

Here root_type is the type and root is the name of the root element of your XML. The same approach works for serialization except you use std::ostringstream:

```
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream ostr;

root (ostr, *r, ...);
std::string str = ostr.str () // Output XML in a string.
```

Comment: A note: the parsing does validation by default, so the dreadded `instance document parsing failed` exception is thrown when the .xsd file can not be found in the executable path. To be on the safe side one might want to try instead: `root_ (istr, xml_schema::flags::dont_validate);`.

Comment: @count0: You can specify the XSD file with xml_schema::properties See for instance stackoverflow.com/a/11267720/757777